# Input elements should have autocomplete attributes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-chrome

I am getting this message in the console I can't understand it. Please look into it

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>registration page</title>
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('form').submit(function(event){
    "use strict";
        var valid = true,
        message = '';    
            $('.error').remove();           
   $('form input').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);   
        if(!$this.val()) {
            message='';
            var inputName = $this.attr('name');
            valid = false;
            message += 'Please enter your ' + inputName + '\n';
            $(this).closest('div').append('<div class="error">'+message+'</div>');           
        }
})
           if(!valid){
                event.preventDefault();
        }else{
$('form').serialize()
        }
})
})
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<div>
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name"><br>
</div>
<div>
    <label>File</label>
    <input type="file" name="file"><br>
</div>
<div>
    <label>password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password"><br>
</div>
<button type='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is despite no error I keep getting this message

```
[DOM] Input elements should have autocomplete attributes (suggested: "current-password"):
```

​

I have been provided with a google link in console which take me to [(More info: goo.gl/9p2vKq)](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/create-amazing-password-forms)

Comment: its better to set autocomplete to "off" it will help later

Answer (score 154, accepted):

Try changing

```
<input type="password" name="password">
```

to

```
<input type="password" name="password" autocomplete="on">
```

[Autocomplete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete) lets web developers specify what (if any) permission the user agent has to provide automated assistance in filling out form field values, as well as guidance to the browser as to the type of information expected in the field.

It's pretty powerful.

Comment: I dont want to use auto complete. It is my-choice. Why is it compulsory?

Comment: It's not, you can also set that value to "off".

Comment: In previous versions of chrome it was not necessary to use auto-complete but now with the updated version we need to specify it

Comment: @vinayakshahdeo I know it is old question/answer/comment But if you use `autocomplete="off"`it shuts the warning down. The warning may sound like it is required but it is not. You just have to specify if it is on or off, it seems like it does not have default value by default.

Comment: Hello @vinayakshahdeo, this is only an information for you as a developer. From a security perspective it's modern consensus and opinion that it is better when users use auto-complete function in combination with really strong long passwords. Otherwise they will more likely choose simple passwords.

Comment: @GeofoxCoding thanks for the advice but I don't think using strong passwords has anything to do with autocomplete rather I would use a regex that forces users to make long passwords.

Comment: @vinayakshahdeo of course you should use RegEx to validate and I'm also not giving my opinion. It's just an info I took from web security courses. It's just an attempt to describe why browsers are designed this way nowadays. Many modern browsers will also not allow to disable autocomplete="off" because it is recommended to use autocomplete for passwords (https://mzl.la/314x8wN). There are still a lot of sites out there that prefer passwords like "MasterYoda51!" instead of "ThisMayBeAVeryVeryLongPasswordPhraseYouCanEasilyRemember"

Answer (score 15):

### Turning off Autocomplete

You have the below [options for working with errors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion) of the below format ***Input elements should have autocomplete attributes*** thrown by the console by modifying:

```html
<input type="password" name="password">
```

1. **Set the `autocomplete` attribute to `off` at the `<form>` or `<input>` which:**

   - Enforces browser to NOT store any data
   - Disables caching form data in the session history

```html
<input type="password" name="password" autocomplete="off">
```

2. **Another way to prevent autofilling by the browser is:**
   *The below suggestions are browser specific*

```html
<input type="password" name="password" autocomplete="new-password"> <!-- For Mozilla-->
<!-- or -->
<input type="password" name="password" autocomplete="current-password"> <!-- For Chrome-->
```

Comment: We need it to be compatible with both browsers we cant write individual cases for each of the browser

Comment: it did but the comment was for second answer

Answer (score 8):

From [Chromium Projects' Design Documents](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/create-amazing-password-forms):

> ##### Autocomplete attributes help password managers to infer the purpose of a field in a form, saving them from accidentally saving or autofilling the wrong data.

You can use the `autocomplete` attribute on an HTML element that needs to be managed by a password manager for automatically filling its value. The value of `autocomplete` attribute depends on the field about which you want to convey more information to the password manager. Consider the following examples:

1. Current password field - `autocomplete="current-password"`
2. New password field - `autocomplete="new-password"`
3. Credit card field - `autocomplete="cc-number"`

Answer (score 2):

Its in chrome.. 
It is to ensure that browsers' and extensions' password management functionality can understand your site's sign-up, sign-in and change-password forms by enriching your HTML with a dash of metadata.

this might help you  https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/form-styles-that-chromium-understands

Comment: I dont want to use auto complete. It is my-choice. Why is it compulsory?

Answer (score 2):

TypeScript 3.9 caused me to use autoComplete -- capital "C"

Answer (score 0):

React with Bootstrap required me to use autoComplete with capital "C" as well.

Comment: react uses camel casing so thats the case why you had to use "C"

Answer (score 0):

I know that the question got answered, this is for those people who want to remove this warning message from console while using "**react.js**"

just add this in the input field

```
              autoComplete="true"
```

---

**here is the full one**

```
 <input type="password" className="form-control" placeholder="Password" 
                          autoComplete="true"
                          name='password'
                          required={true} />
```

Answer (score 0):

In React, input element can have autoComplete prop.
This prop helps users to fill forms faster, especially on mobile devices.
The name can be confusing, as it's more like an autofill.
You can learn more about it from : https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#autofill